# How to take a field value and need to update that field value to rest of sub arrays using jolt transformation in nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

there is field Version it has some value in first object array, and the value will be dynamic and that value should be assigned to rest of subarrays of same field which is Version field.

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "kcltechsw.com",
    "AccountName": "KCLSW-AZRP-SAAS",
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "MEU Core Team",
    "AccountName": "AAA_MEU Master Account",
    "Version": null
  },
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "MEU Core Team",
    "AccountName": "AAA_MEU Master Account",
    "Version": null
  },
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "Unassigned",
    "AccountName": "KCL_Finastra_Barita",
    "Version": null
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```json
[
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "kcltechsw.com",
    "AccountName": "KCLSW-AZRP-SAAS",
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "MEU Core Team",
    "AccountName": "AAA_MEU Master Account",
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "MEU Core Team",
    "AccountName": "AAA_MEU Master Account",
    "Version": 1
  },
  {
    "InvoiceSectionName": "Unassigned",
    "AccountName": "KCL_Finastra_Barita",
    "Version": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update by using **notNull** function within a **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation spec in order to conditionally check whether the value is *null* and eligible to be converted to *1* such as

```json
[
  { // generate the first encountered value of "Version"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": {
        "Version": "&First"
      },
      "@": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Version": ["=notNull(@(1,&))", "=(@(3,VersionFirst))"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick original array of objects only 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "*": "[&]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Ozhan Thanks for u r response but the Version Value will not be same it is dynamically changing, So whatever the value that first Object array Version field has that value will be reflect to rest of the sub Object arrays in same Version field.

Comment: You're right @pandu , I've just edited.